# Subtract (mask away?) a path by a circle shape

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, graphics

I'm drawing a path in Flex using Spark:Path.

I want to subtract a circle shape from this path, as in the following image:

[image]

(The path is black and wide)

Any ideas?

I tried creating a mask using a Shape object but couldn't quite manage to create a mask that has a circular hole in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it.

No masks involved.

I took the `Path` and wrapped a `Group` around it:

```
<s:Group blendMode="layer">
    <s:Path id="connector" ... />
    <s:Ellipse id="hole" blendMode="erase">
```

I set the `blendMode` to "layer" and added an ellipse *after* the path with blendMode `erase`

Comment: I learned something new today. Didn't know about either of these blend modes.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a mask for this, just use the [`curveTo()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#curveTo%28%29) method of the Graphics class:

```
var shape1:Shape = new Shape();
shape1.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
shape1.graphics.moveTo(0,0);
shape1.graphics.lineTo(80,0);
shape1.graphics.curveTo(110,30,140,0);
shape1.graphics.lineTo(300,0);
shape1.graphics.lineTo(300,20);
shape1.graphics.lineTo(0,20);
shape1.graphics.lineTo(0,0);
shape1.graphics.endFill();
```

Which gives you:

[image]

This is obviously not using your exact dimensions, but demonstrates the principle.

Comment: I'm not drawing with Shape - I'm just trying to mask with it. My path object is a Spark:Path, and it needs to be a Spark:Path because I'm adding filters to it, etc. So I have this Path object out of which I want to take a "bite" in a circular shape. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @gigantt - I'm not so sure about any Flex-related specifics, but in more general terms you can still use the above code, using the dimensions of your Path to set the shape's dimensions.  Then apply this shape as the mask to your Path. Hopefully that would work with a Spark:Path too.