# How to remove shapes from filled SVG path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/1spn8nne/1/

This has two paths, for now, they are just rect but are actually complicated shape. I have used this code to create two rects with 'holes' in :

```
createRects(dataPointsPath2, 'blue');
createHoles(dataPointsCircle2);
createRects(dataPointsPath1, 'red');
createHoles(dataPointsCircle1);
```

What I need are the holes to be removed from the filled path so you can see the rect behind it.

How do I go about removing a shape (circle) from a filled path ?

EDIT

I have just realised, a clip path will probably work well for this, I'll try implement but if someone has any ideas I'd appreciate the help :)

Comment: no, thats just putting fill of none on the circles. I want those circles to be removed from the corresponding filled paths, i.e the rectangles

Comment: Oh you mean instead of having a rect + circle, you want a rect - circle ?

Comment: exactly @TimB, I think clip-path will work well, trying to implement now

Comment: I'm unsure on how to implement what you have said. How to put the circle on the same path ? And how to set the direction and so on.

Comment: If creating your circles as a subpath is proving tricky, an alternative is to use a mask. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579508/subtract-one-circle-from-another-in-svg/22581434#22581434

Comment: @PaulLeBeau can this be used in my example ? I.e have multiple masks on one filled path ?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I've managed to solve this :) shall add my own answer, thank you

Comment: "have multiple masks on one filled path ?" No what you do is have one mask with multiple holes (circles)

Comment: yep thats what I ended up finding out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way to draw a rect with a hole in. It relies on the evenodd fill-rule. The circle is inside the rect it becomes a hole in the rect and the blue background shows through.

```html
  <svg viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue"/>
    <path fill="#b4edb4" fill-rule="evenodd"  d="M230,230H8V13h223
  V236z M 120 80 a 50 50 0 1 0 0.00001 0z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Great stuff, this will help a lot, thanks, appreciate it

Comment: Do you have any idea how to create the combined path from the data I provided ? I have the points for the rect and points for the circles in the question

Comment: Tthe circle is formed from the elliptical arc (a command, the prior M command and the final Z). The rest form the rect.

Comment: Thanks again, sorry to be a pain but do you know how to produce this via D3 using the data I have provided ?

Comment: I'm too lazy to do that. Try it yourself and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: Aren't we all, no worries appreciate the help :)

Comment: @RobertLongson Marvelous, what a great answer! But, if I am not mistaken, the evenodd [fill-rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillRuleProperty) won't take the direction of the crossed path segments into account, right? That's something used to evaluate the insideness for the nonzero fill-rule.

Comment: @altocumulus Indeed, I misremembered, evenodd just needs the circle to be iside the rect, nonzero would require directionality too.

Answer (score 1):

@Robert Longson gave a nice answer but I was unable to duplicate it using my dataset and D3. So, thanks to @PaulLeBeau for his point about [masks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking).

For the mask, you need a rect element, filled white for it to work. It uses this to know what to mask against(I think).

```
var thisMask = thisContainer.append("svg:mask")
    .attr("id", board + '_mask')

  thisMask.append("rect")
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('width', "100%")
    .attr('height', "100%")
    .style('fill','white')
```

And in the same mask element, you need the rest of the shapes you want to remove from the path.

So in my case, I wanted a collection of circles :

```
thisMask.selectAll('.circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      console.log('clippath', d)
      return d.x
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y
    })
    .attr('r', function(d) {
      return d.radius
    })
```

And that's it. I have updated the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/1spn8nne/4/